# How to use the new IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer' in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, idle-timer

The IdleTimer was rewritten from scratch in [v5](https://idletimer.dev/docs/getting-started/new), and the usage changed completely. They do have an [example](https://idletimer.dev/docs/api/with-idle-timer#idletimer-component) of how use it "the old way", but it's written for class based components. I need help translating that to a functional component.

This is their example:

```
  import { Component } from 'react'
  import { withIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'

  class IdleTimerComponent extends Component {
    render () {
      return this.props.children
    }
  }

  export const IdleTimer = withIdleTimer(IdleTimerComponent)
```

and then use it like this from the app:

```
render () {
    return (
      <>
        <IdleTimer
          ref={ref => { this.idleTimer = ref }}
          timeout={1000 * 60 * 15}
          promptTimeout={1000 * 30}
          onPrompt={this.onPrompt}
          onIdle={this.onIdle}
          onAction={this.onAction}
          onActive={this.onActive}
          startManually
        />
        <HomePage />
      </>
    )
  }
```

How do I do this in a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

```
// How to implement in functional Component and are you using "react-idle- 
timer": "^4.2.9", then do this all

// IdleTimer states 
const idleTimer = () => {
    const [timeout, setTimeOut] = useState(1000 * 10 * 1)
    const [isTimedOut, setTimedOut] = useState(false)
    let idleTimer = HTMLElement | null;

    const onAction = (e) => {
        console.log('user did something', e)
        setTimedOut(false)
    }

    const onActive = (e) => {
        console.log('user is active', e)
        setTimedOut(false)
    }

    const onIdle = () => {
        debugger
        if (isTimedOut) {
            if (loginUserData.length > 0) {
                // Your SingOut function call here

            }
        } else {
            idleTimer?.reset()
            setTimedOut(true)
        }
        console.log("IdleTimer", idleTimer)

    }

    return (
        <>
            <IdleTimer
                ref={ref => { idleTimer = ref }}
                element={document}
                onActive={onActive}
                onIdle={onIdle}
                onAction={onAction}
                debounce={250}
                timeout={timeout}
            />
        </>
    )
}
export default idleTimer;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./utils/ProtectedRoutes";
import { useAppDispatch } from "./utils/hooks";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import AddTeamData from "./components/AddTeamData";
import Authenticate from "./components/Authenticate";
import TeamData from "./components/TeamData";
import { setUser } from './actions/authActions';
import './App.css';
import Verification from "./components/Verification";
import { useIdleTimer, IIdleTimer } from "react-idle-timer";
import ForgetPassword from "./components/ForgetPassword";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {`enter code here`
      dispatch(setUser());
    }
  }, [window.location.pathname, token]);

  const [state, setState] = useState<string>('Active');
  const [remaining, setRemaining] = useState<number>(0);

  const onIdle = () => {
    console.log('user is idle');
    setState('Idle');
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  };

  const onActive = () => {
    console.log('user is active');
    setState('Active');
  };

  const handleAction = (event?: Event, idleTimer?: IIdleTimer) => {
    if (remaining >= 40) {
      console.log("here" , event)
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("resetting");
      reset();
    }
    console.log('user did something', event);
  };

  const { getRemainingTime, reset } = useIdleTimer({
    onIdle,
    onActive,
    onAction: handleAction,
    timeout: 20 * 60 * 1000,
    throttle: 500,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(
      () => setRemaining(Number((getRemainingTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))),
      1000
    );
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [getRemainingTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('refresh_token') == null) {
      return;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {remaining > 40 && (
        <div className="fixed w-full h-screen bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-80 flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="bg-white opacity-100 p-5 rounded-lg flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <div className="text-center text-xl">
              <h1>You will be logged out in</h1>
              <h1 className="text-red-400">
                {Number(Math.floor(remaining / 60))}m : {remaining % 60}s{" "}
              </h1>
            </div>
            <p className="w-[80%] text-center py-3">
              You have been Inactive for some time. Do you want to continue
              using the site?
            </p>
            <div className="flex gap-4">
              <button className="h-9 px-3 rounded-full bg-green-400 text-white hover:bg-white hover:text-green-400 border border-green-400">
                Yes
              </button>
              <button className="h-9 px-3 rounded-full bg-red-400 text-white hover:bg-white hover:text-red-400 border border-red-400">
                No, Logout
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/authenticate" element={<Authenticate />} />
          <Route path="/verification" element={<Verification />} />
          <Route path="/reset-password" element={<ForgetPassword />} />
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/team-data" element={<TeamData />} />
            <Route
              path="/add-team-data/:invitationId"
              element={<AddTeamData />}
            />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

````
import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer' 

export const App = () => {
  const onPrompt = () => {
    // Fire a Modal Prompt
  }

  const onIdle = () => {
    // Close Modal Prompt
    // Do some idle action like log out your user
  }

  const onActive = (event) => {
    // Close Modal Prompt
    // Do some active action
  }

  const onAction = (event) => {
    // Do something when a user triggers a watched event
  }

  const {
    start,
    reset,
    activate,
    pause,
    resume,
    isIdle,
    isPrompted,
    isLeader,
    getTabId,
    getRemainingTime,
    getElapsedTime,
    getLastIdleTime,
    getLastActiveTime,
    getTotalIdleTime,
    getTotalActiveTime
  } = useIdleTimer({
    onPrompt,
    onIdle,
    onActive,
    onAction,
    timeout: 1000 * 60 * 20,
    promptTimeout: 0,
    events: [
      'mousemove',
      'keydown',
      'wheel',
      'DOMMouseScroll',
      'mousewheel',
      'mousedown',
      'touchstart',
      'touchmove',
      'MSPointerDown',
      'MSPointerMove',
      'visibilitychange'
    ],
    immediateEvents: [],
    debounce: 0,
    throttle: 0,
    eventsThrottle: 200,
    element: document,
    startOnMount: true,
    startManually: false,
    stopOnIdle: false,
    crossTab: false,
    name: 'idle-timer',
    syncTimers: 0,
    leaderElection: false
  })
  return (
    <HomePage />
  )
}```
````

Comment: Thanks, but I need something else .. I need a way to use their withIdleTimer HOC.

Comment: ** export default withIdleTimer (App)**